# How to Instantiate Fragment through Activity on App Resume or Re-load Object into Memory?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

Java Exception: http://hastebin.com/yiwecefifi.avrasm

I have an object, that I call Category, that my fragment (A CategoryFragment [extending ListFragment]) needs to have access to in order to fill the ListView with content.

Normally, this works fine.  The app starts, the categories are created, and the lists show up (As I have several of these in a ViewPager).

However, after pressing Home and staying away for a bit, re-entering the app will cause a crash.  Before I created a constructor with a parameter, it would give me a NullPointerException to the category.  Since then, I decided to give it a constructor with the category object, and now it fails in this manner.

So then, my question is one of two things:

1. How do I force the instantiation of the fragment through my activity? *or*
2. How do I make Android keep my object?  I assume it'll need to be serializable, but how do I keep it available when the Fragment is created again?

The manifest data for this activity is below:

```
<activity
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:name=".NewsActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
    android:label="@string/shortcut_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.BgsuNews" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link in the docs about saving activity state](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#SavingActivityState) should be useful. Fragments also have the `onSave/RestoreInstanceState()` functions like activities. You would need to decide which class your Category object belongs to (the Activity or the Fragment), and save and restore your Category data via the `Bundle` passed to you in the `onSave/RestoreInstanceState()` functions of that class.

For another way to store work in progress there's [this approach](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState), which may or may not be useful in your case. (It's what I do wherever possible, and onSaveInstanceState() works well for everything else.)

Comment: Thank you.  I'm pretty sure this is what I was trying to figure out, and I'll mark you as answer once I confirm. :3

Sometimes, its just difficult to find exactly what you're looking for, like looking for a certain colour of lego in the bucket.